# Side effects of database and schema rename

Tags: database, schema, cluster-analysis, rename, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have some tables automatically clustered in database D and schema PUBLIC. We are going to rename the database and the schema with the commands :

```
ALTER DATABASE D RENAME TO D_RENAMED

ALTER SCHEMA PUBLIC RENAME TO PRODUCTION
```

We would like to know please if there is something else we have to do for this operation and if there is some side effect after this operation especially in term of cost for the automatic clustering. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rename operation is simply a metadata change. There is no impact in terms of costs in renaming a schema.

The only impact will be on SQL queries that were explicitly using the old schema name will break. You may want to double-check that permissions on the schema are what you expect too.

Rather than renaming the public schema why not just `clone` it to a schema named `production` instead? That way you get to keep the `public` schema, which is always created with a new database. Even this will have no impact on costs despite there being two schemas with the same data (unless you make a bunch of modifications in both due to time travel/failsafe storage). see [cloning documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/object-clone.html)